# Android - How can I split the date format to year, month and day from String to int?

Tags: android, sqlite, simpledateformat

I would like to ask if I have a date with dd/mm/yyyy in String format, I want to split it to int year, int month and int day, how can to that.

Other than that, the String date (dd/mm/yyyy) is stored in the SQLite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I done... Thank you the above answer as a references~~ ^^

```
String insertDate = EventListAdapter.KEY_DATE;
String[] items1 = insertDate.split("/");
            String d1=items1[0];
            String m1=items1[1];
            String y1=items1[2];
            int d = Integer.parseInt(d1);
            int m = Integer.parseInt(m1);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(y1);
```

Answer (score 7):

you split this way also

```
String date="dd/mm/yyyy";
String[] items1 = date.split("/");
String date1=items1[0];
String month=items1[1];
String year=items1[2];
```

Comment: now it will work. good that you edited your post. it was wrong splitting by //

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String startDateString = "01/26/2013";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
        Date startDate=null;
        String newDateString = null;
        try 
        {
            startDate = df.parse(startDateString);
            System.out.println("month===>>>"+(startDate.getMonth()+1));
            System.out.println("date===>>>"+startDate.getDate());
            System.out.println("year===>>>"+(startDate.getYear()+1900));

        } catch (Exception e)//(ParseException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Split method of the string object and cast the resulting strings to int

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

If possible, you will find date handling easier if you store the Long date value that you get from Calendar.getTimeInMilliseconds

Storing dates as string with no regard to locale is inviting errors later.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 

 Date d = df.parse("String date (dd/mm/yyyy) is stored in the SQLite");

 int month = d.getMonth();

 int day= d.getDay();

 int year = d.getYear();
```

Comment: this is deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

Dates are very delicate. Usually a date has to be in rererence to a position (timezone).

Either use the classes Java provides like Date and Calendar together with a TimeZone to interpret the String correctly into a real date object, or if you don't care about the position of that date at all you can use String.split() to get an array, check the correct form and call Interger.valueOf on each of the parts.

Answer (score 0):

Split string using "/"

```
String s= "15/5/2013";
String arr[] =s.split("/");
System.out.println("Date = "+arr[0]);
System.out.println("Month = "+arr[1]);
System.out.println("Year = "+arr[2]);
```

Output

```
Date = 15
Month = 5
Year = 2013
```